# Object disposed problem in caching scenario

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I've written a class that enables caching of objects for a certain amount of time. The Cache.cs class uses a delegate to refresh the data in the cache if this time period expires.

I have for instance a class called DatumService which holds all the rows from a table called Datum. This table hardly ever changes so it safe to keep them in memory. I've set the expiration to 1 hour.

After an hour the routine below is called.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all Datum records to be cached.
    /// </summary>
    private List<Datum> GetDatums()
    {
        return ModelContext
            .Datums
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
    }
```

This method makes a call using the Entity Framework to refill the cache with all 'Datum' rows.

The problem I have is with the current implementation of ModelContext.

The Datum service consumes the ServiceBase class which gets injected with the IServiceProvider.

```
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider { get; set; } = default!;

    public ServiceBase(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = provider;
    }
    
    public ModelContext? ModelContext => _serviceProvider.GetService<ModelContext>();
```

Earlier I injected the ModelContext into this class but that causes the same problem.

The ModelContext is received from Microsofts Dependency Injection. When the cache expires and the call is made I get an 'Object Disposed' exception on the IServiceProvider object.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There's a number of issues here. Most likely you have mismatched lifestyles for your objects. In addition, you're using a service locator anti-pattern, which is contributing to your lifestyle problem. And finally, I would argue that you should decouple caching from the repository itself and raise it up a layer.

Comment: What do you mean with lifestyle. Did you confuse it with livecycle?

Comment: What do you mean with decouple caching from the repository? And how do you suggest I should do that. The same question for 'raise it up a layer'. It's not clear to me what you mean with these 2 suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `ModelContext` and `IServiceProvider` are resolved from some scope which ends by the time you want to refresh the cache resulting in the observed behaviour (scope will dispose all transient and scoped services created by it on scope completion). One way to fix this is to inject `IServiceScopeFactory` and create scope when cache needs to be refreshed:

```
private IServiceProvider _scopeFactory { get; set; };

public CacheRefreshingService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
{
    _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
}

private List<Datum> GetDatums()
{
    using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ModelContext>();
    return ModelContext
        .Datums
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
}
```

But I would suggest to look into refactoring the whole thing a bit (it is hard to say how exactly without seeing the code)

Comment: Ah, ok, sounds like a solution to me. Yes of course it's livecycle is scoped. Hmmm, I need to surround all cached calls with a scope which is released after the action is finished. Yes needs refactoring.

Comment: Changed the caching code to use the IServiceScopeFactory and now hand the refresh routine the scope. The cache routine has to get the ModelContext with that scope (with using) and it works fine. Problem solved. Thank you very much.